# how to displaying data array with echo in php?

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I  Have an array like this, who I `print_r()` from a sql query:

```
Array (

    [rfq_number] => 

    [id] => 3 

    [nama_customer] => syaifudin amin 

    [date] => 07-10-2009 

    [ship_to] => syaifudin 

    [terms] => prepaid

    [phone] => 08378979487 

    [description] => deskription1,deskription2,deskription3

    [quot_no] => 034932890355436 

    [detail] => Array ( )

)
```

how to convert it to a regular array and displaying with echo?

Comment: What is a regular array in your eyes? Can you give a sample output and the code you tried?

Comment: usualy i using this way $cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");

Comment: You dont want the keys?

Comment: Do you want to make the array index-based? Therefore you could use a foreach loop, and your keys can be replaced with the indexes.
so rfq_number would get to 0, 
id to 1, and so on
But I suggest you using the keys, it keeps semantics in your application.

Comment: I suggest we don't guess and wait for the OP to tell us.

Comment: the above array is good,and easy to manipulate.what's the problem actually?

Comment: @ Coder55 I just echo an array variabel but error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for a single item.

```
echo $dataquotationc['phone'];
```

You would repeat with each item, displaying it where you want on your page.

Comment: this is work my bro thanx, echo $dataquotationc['phone'];  and now how to get length array ? to loop it.

Comment: Do you mean loop through multiple rows?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to `echo` each field in the array?

```
foreach ($arr['detail'] as $key => $value) {
    if (gettype($value) == 'array') {
        $value = join(" ", $value);
    }
    echo 'Key: ' . $key . ' Val: ' . $value . '<Br >';
}
```

Comment: I think this is what he means, yes.

Comment: @Burning Crystals, I am Trying your code like this <?php foreach ($$dataquotationc['detail'] as $key => $value) {
echo 'Key: ' . $key . ' Value: ' . $value; but not work. what is key,value?

Comment: @Alimin you have an extra `$` in your code after `<?php foreach (` 
can you try removing it and run the code again?

Comment: `<?php foreach ($dataquotationc['detail'] as $key => $value) { echo 'Key: ' . $key . ' Value: ' . $value;}` your code should look like this. Key is the identifier in the array and value is.. the Key's value. It works like `'name' => 'John Doe'`. so that you can call `'John Doe'` with `$my_array['name']`

Comment: after remove extra "$", I get message: Array to string conversion, what is the meaning?

Comment: You are also trying to `echo` another `array` inside the loop. your `detail` field contains another array in it

Comment: @Alimin I updated the code to `echo` out everything if the `value` of `detail` is an array. can you try that one?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just wanting to display the output for debugging, have toy tried either of these:

```
var_dump($dataquotationc);

print_r ($dataquotationc);
```

Comment: no, my debuging is over, when  I use print_r(). program running well. I want to using echo, but I can't.